# How to upgrade OSS to new version with local changes?

Tags: open-source, merge, orchardcms

I'm working on a project where we are using the [Orchard CMS](http://orchardproject.net/).

We've made some modules and themes of our own for the CMS and had to make some code changes in the Orchard sources also. This isn't a very good practice of course, because these changes will disappear when upgrading the CMS or something like that. However, making these changes was inevitable at the time, because the default functionality didn't work as our customer wanted.

Now, all of these changes were made on an older version, 1.5.1, and now we need to move on to the new version (1.6 at the moment). By doing this we will lose all the changes we've made to the Orchard sources.

I've already bundled all the changes we've made to the default sources in 1 changeset, so merging them into the new version of the CMS has been made a bit easier. However, this isn't a really good workflow in my opinion.

We could choose to fork the project and make the changes in the fork, but we will have the same difficulties when upgrading, as we still need to merge all of our changes when we upgrade the fork.
Creating pull-requests isn't really an option either, because it's likely the changes won't make it in the master repository or not all users will like the changes.

Is there some other common practice we can use in this project?

**Note:** At the moment I'm asking this for the project I'm working on, but I'd like to know in general how to work with OSS projects where you need to change the sources of a project and still want to get the latest version once in a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you cloned the Orchard repo, you can pull changes from it at any time. You may have to resolve some conflicts with a compare tool where you changed a file that was also changed in the orchard repo since your latest merge. It's relatively painless though.

I keep a copy of my repo on bitbucket and just pull from the orchard repo when they release new versions. Typically I need to resolve conflicts for the solution file, and a couple things here and there. Once these conflicts are resolved, you don't need to deal with them again each time you update. That would only happen where there are files that both you and Orchard are changing. (Like the solution file)

Comment: Sounds like a good workflow. Get a specific version of the repo and when there's a new (major) version, get the new version. The DVCS will make sure all commits will be done individually.
Merges will only be necessary on the files we've changed ourself.

Thanks!